# Date Range Filters in Membership Reports

Tags: civireport

Under **Membership Reports**, if you go to the filters tab and try to select a date from the **Date Range** feature, the calendar is greyed out and there is no year field next to the month. I am attaching a screen shot which is on Joomla 3.9.27 and Civi Version 5.37.2 with PHP 7.3.21.

This issue is there on all our civi installations in both Joomla and WordPress. Strangely I could not find this issue discussed anywhere.

Appreciate if anyone has any idea as to what could cause this or what we could do about this.

Thanks:)
Sri
[image: Sample Screen Shot]

Comment: Maybe check Administer - Customize - Date Prefs and see if anything looks wrong there?

Comment: Thanks Demerit... I checked any everything is in their default settings.
I checked : Administer > Customize Data and Screens > Date Preferences & Administer > Localization > Date Formats

Comment: FWIW, this is behaving correctly on dmaster

Comment: Thank for checking on this Aidan. So Perhaps the it is related to an issue on my hosting (the php version perhaps). I will try changing it and see.